# Migration Repository Oracle Sql Developer

Tags: git, oracle, oracle11g, gitlab, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to connect a live database to GitLab through Oracle SQL Developer. I have a Git connection working in "Team", and an active connection in database. How can I connect the two? I think it has something to do with the "Migration Repository" option, but it does not seem to work.